# Error running app :@react-native-community_art:checkDebugManifest FAILED

Tags: android, react-native

I need to update a project that uses react-native, first I needed to update the SDK version and everything went well. But I also need to update my project's gradle version which currently uses version 6.5, when trying to update to version 7.2 I get the following error:

> Task :@react-native-community_art:checkDebugManifest FAILED

**buid.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.3.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url ("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
       
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-all.zip
```

**gradle.properties**

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8    
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true

MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=debug.keystore
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=androiddebugkey
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=xxxxx
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=xxxxx
```

I'm new to react-native so thanks in advance for any help as I've been stuck on this issue for a few hours.

Comment: Can I see your gradle.properties file?

Comment: @LouaySleman yes, I edited my question and added the gradle.properties file

Comment: I'll add an answer but I'm not pretty sure about it, please tell me if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
buildscript {
 ext {
  buildToolsVersion = "30.0.3"
  minSdkVersion = 21 // <--now use this
  compileSdkVersion = 31
  targetSdkVersion = 31
 }
}
```

and in your android manifest add `android:exported="true"` to the  `\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml` files activity section. For example:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:exported="true"> // <- add it here. ! . ! <intent-filter> <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> </intent-filter> </activity>
```

and just after that:

```
cd .\android\
./gradlew clean
```

Because you're using Gradle 7 maven is removed and you need to replace it So, instead of using:

`apply plugin: 'maven'`

you should use

`apply plugin: 'maven-publish'`

Comment: Thanks for answering. I made the changes but it didn't work for me, I ended up encountering new problems. The app still doesn't compile and when I sync the project in Android studio I get the two new errors.

`Caused by: org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin with id 'maven' not found.`

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: compileSdkVersion is not specified.`

Comment: I'll edit my answer

Comment: I updated my answer, hope it works for you